# Upgrade from Tridion 2009 SP1 to 2013 SP1 - Is the Legacy Pack required?

Tags: 2013, upgrade, legacy-pack

In the upgrade manual for Tridion 2013 SP1 it states that:

> If you are upgrading from SDL Tridion 2009 SP1, open a command prompt,
>   access the SDL Tridion installation media, navigate to the Content
>   Manager\ directory and enter the following command:
>
> SDLTridion2013CM.exe LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE

My 2009 SP1 implementation doesn't use: VBScript templates, the Business Connector, has no TOM code, doesn't use workflow or event system.

I'm also installing the Contener Manager fresh on a new server so just the database will be upgraded really.

Is the Legacy Pack actually required in this scenario? My thinking is no and I will probably just isntall it anyway but thought it would be interesting to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might think you are not, but it might be tricky to be 100% sure. For example, if you have at least 1 VBScript template, you CME will choke as soon as you open folder containing this template. And keep in mind that in previous versions, there were default VBScript templates.

Also, if it's not the case - you still have your default Workflows with VBScript activities.

My advise is to get rid of all VBScript templates, do not install legacy pack. Check if everything is still ok. If it is - go and update your workflows. If it's not - run installer with `LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE` and modify your installation by adding legacy pack.

Comment: Ah, good point on the default templates. I'll give your method a try.

Comment: Don't forget about any in process workflows. If keeping them during the upgrade, they will all need the Legacy Pack (VBScript Workflow) in order to work.

Comment: Easiest way to get set up would be to have two servers pointing to the same db, one with legacy pack and the other without.

Comment: Is there any issue running the installer with LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE on top of an already installed server (installed without lecacy pack)?

Comment: @InmaculadaPalacios No, there's no issue